# Error while conditionally adding columns to an existing dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to conditionally add a column to a data frame. I have a column named `comments` which has a text-based on English and German languages. I basically want to detect the language and add a new column with a value `en` or `de` depending on the translation.

```
library(googleLanguageR)
df$language <- ifelse(df$comments %>% 
                           gl_translate_detect() %>% 
                           pull(language) == "en","en", "de"
                         )
```

However, I get

```
Error: NA/NaN argument
```

Expected:

```
title | comments        | language  
-----------------------------------
A     | I like...       |   en  
B     | I wish...       |   en  
C     | Das ist....     |   de  
C     | Es war...       |   de  
C     | Most of the...  |   en  
...
```

EDIT: output of `gl_translate_detect()`

```
A tibble:1 x 4
confidence  isReliable  language  text
<dbl>         <lgl>     <chr>     <chr>
0.983067      FALSE       de    Dem  ich mich.
```

Comment: Who you Create a Google API Console Project ?

Comment: Yes, I make use of an API key from Google to do the translation.

Comment: What `gl_translate_detect()` returns ?

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: Would you try `df$language <- ifelse( gl_translate_detect(df$comments) 
                           [["language"]] == "en","en", "de"
                         )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to using other packages? I cannot use `googleLanguageR` on my PC. But its documentation suggests using the package `cld2`.

From the documentation

> Consider using library(cld2) and cld2::detect_language instead offline, since that is free and
> local without needing a paid API call.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleLanguageR/googleLanguageR.pdf (pg.15)

```
# install.packages("cld2")
x = cld2::detect_language("katten sidder på måtten")
y = cld2::detect_language("how are you")
x
y
```

```
> x
[1] "da"
> y
[1] "en"
```